# Invalid filter clause. Microsoft.Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, migration, pipeline

I'm trying to get an Azure AD Role Assignment using Microsoft.Graph PowerShell module.

I'm running a command below:

```
$assignments = Get-MgGroupAppRoleAssignment -GroupId $group.Id  -Filter "ResourceId eq '$($sp.Id)'" | Format-List
```

where $sp is the service principal object that was successfully found.

I'm getting the next error:

```
##[error]Invalid filter clause
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

I was trying to replace the old AzureAD command Get-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment with the new Microsoft.Graph Get-MgGroupAppRoleAssignment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting this error is because you are passing the resource id as string. Resource id type is actually a GUID.

Please try the following command:

```
$assignments = Get-MgGroupAppRoleAssignment -GroupId $group.Id  -Filter "ResourceId eq $($sp.Id)" | Format-List
```

Comment: Yes, it was an issue. Thank you!